# Node-Webkit frameless app covers taskbar when maximized

Tags: node-webkit

I am developing an app in Node-Webkit (using the latest version, 0.9.2). When the main window (which is a frameless window) gets maximized, it covers the whole screen, including the taskbar, which is obviously not what I want.

I am using Windows 8.1. On OS X the maximize functionality works as expected. I am not able to verify this on Windows 7 and Linux at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How do you maximize the app, are you using require('nw.gui').Window.get().maximize()? I'm not experiencing the same issue on Windows 7.

If there is indeed an issue on Windows 8.1, you can just implement the resize method yourself in JS. Not too fancy, but it will work as a workaround until the next version of NW is released...

```
var nw = require('nw.gui').Window.get();
nw.resizeTo(screen.availWidth, screen.availHeight);
nw.moveTo(0, 0);
```

or

```
var nw = require('nw.gui').Window.get();
nw.setMaximumSize(screen.availWidth, screen.availHeight);
```

Hope this helps...

EDIT: Looks like a [known issue](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/issues/1021) on NW. The solutions suggested in the thread are similar to the solutions suggested above.

Comment: Yes, I am indeed using `require('nw.gui').Window.get().maximize()` to maximize my window.

Comment: I will check if it can be reproduced on W8.1. I'm adding another alternative.